# pytest and Django transactional database

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I use production database for tests (actually it's test database in docker). The question is: how to make tests run in transactions against this database. I need the same behavior like `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)` but with production database.

Current setup:

conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup():
    """Avoid creating/setting up the test database"""
    pass


@pytest.fixture
def db(request, django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    django_db_blocker.unblock()


@pytest.fixture
def myfixture(db):
    ...
    return SomeObject
```

test_example.py

```
def test_something(db, myfixture):
    assert ...
```

Comment: It's all in the settings: [`DATABASES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution.

Add fixtures loading code to `db` fixture:

conftest.py

```
from django.core.management import call_command

@pytest.fixture
def db(request, django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    django_db_blocker.unblock()
    call_command('loaddata', 'fixture.json')
```

And use `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)` with tests:

test_example.py

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def test_something(db, myfixture):
    assert ...
```

After each test pytest will flush your database and fill it with fixtures data.